# Help with integrating $\int \frac{t^3}{1+t^2} ~dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

What am I doing wrong on this integration problem?

$$
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{t^3}{1+t^2} &= 
\frac14 t^4 (\ln(1+t^2) (t+\frac13 t^3))
\\ &= \frac14 t^4(t \ln(1+t^2)+\frac13 t^3 \ln(1+t^2)
\\ &= \frac14 t^5 \ln(1+t^2)+\frac{1}{3}t^7 \ln(1+t^2)
\end{align*}$$

Answer should be $\frac{1}{2}(t^2-\ln(t^2+1))$. I'm way off

Any help appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're doing anything right.  You seem to be trying to apply a sort of chain rule that says that if $F'=f$ and $G'=g$ then $\int f(g(x))\,dx = F(g(x))G(x)+C$.  That is not true.

Comment: Five answers and I am the only person who has up-voted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integral is:

$$\int \frac{t^3}{1+t^2} dt$$

Substitute: $x = 1+t^2$ and thus $dx = 2t dt$. Then the above transforms to:

$$\int \frac{t^3}{1+t^2} dt = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{t^2 \ 2t dt}{(1+t^2)}$$

Using the transformation suggested earlier, we can re-write the right hand side as:

$$\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{(x-1) \ dx}{x}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: ok, yea Should be able to go from there, thanks!

Comment: hmm, where did that 1/2 come from? edit, nvm I see we need it to get 2dt

Comment: I multiplied the denominator and the numerator by 2. See the second equation. There is a 2 in the numerator. I did this because the transformation requires that $dx = 2t dt$.

Comment: It will be $\frac{1}{2}(x-\ln(x))$, right? Which is $\frac{1}{2}((t^2+1)-\ln(t^2+1))$ not the one the OP posted.

Comment: You forgot a constant. The additional $\frac{1}{2}$ gets absorbed into that constant.

Comment: @tards: Right, both of them are correct.

Answer (score 4):

The first step is not correct.  You can write $\frac{t^3}{1+t^2}=t-\frac{t}{1+t^2}$  The first term integrates to $t^2/2$, the second yields to $u=t^2$

Comment: I guess im confused with that rewrite, how can you come to that?

Comment: @Matt:[Partial fraction decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html).

Comment: @Matt: Long division can be used for that.

Answer (score 1):

Ummmm....how did you arrive at $\frac{1}{4}t^4\left(\ln(1+t^2)\left(t+\frac{1}{3}t^3\right)\right)$?

Hint:  How about a substitution to make the denominator of $\frac{t^3}{1+t^2}$ a bit more manageable to integrate?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't like substituting too much, I prefer a more "creative" approach:

\begin{align}\int \frac{t^3}{1+t^2}dt&=\int\frac{t^3+t-t}{1+t^2}dt\\&=\int \frac{t(1+t^2)}{1+t^2}dt-\int \frac{t}{1+t^2}dt\\&=\int t\ dt-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2t}{1+t^2}dt\\&=\frac{t^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+t^2)+C.\end{align}

I find it's easier this way, where possible.

Comment: `"Personally, I don't like substituting too much"`, but you need substitution $u=1+t^2$ to evaluate
$$
\int\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\ dt.
$$
Your approach is also similar with Ross Millikan's. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Oh, I guess you're right, that is technically a substitution. I'm so used to recognising that one that one that I don't substitute it :P

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int \frac{t^3}{1+t^2}\, dt = \int \frac{t^2}{1+t^2} \Big( \underbrace{{}\quad t\, dt\quad{}}_{\text{HINT}}\Big) = \int \frac{u}{1+u} \Big(\frac 1 2 \, du \Big) = \int \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+u} \right) \Big(\frac 1 2 \, du \Big)
$$